# Magento 2.3.4 low stock report only showing items when stock level is 0 and marked as in stock then saved manually

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.3.4, reports

When the qty of a product is 1 and is sold it doesn't show up in the low stock report, when that same product is marked as shipped it doesn't show up in the low stock report but when I manually save the product as qty 0 and in stock it changes to out of stock and it shows up in the low stock report. Out of stock threshold is set to 0 Anyone had this issue or knows how to fix it?